# Loop through non-consecutive bit positions

Tags: bit-manipulation

How to iterate through the `2^n` values consisting of `n` non-consecutive bits defined by a given mask `m` (of hamming weight `n`).

Example: 16-bit variables, `n=3`, `m=0x0103`.
The `2^3=8` values produced should be:

```
    (binary)         (hex)
0000000000000000    0x0000
0000000000000001    0x0001
0000000000000010    0x0002
0000000000000011    0x0003
0000000100000000    0x0100
0000000100000001    0x0101
0000000100000010    0x0102
0000000100000011    0x0103
```

I believe this can be done in `c*2^n`operations, for a small `c`(1 or 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is how to get from the previous value to the next one.

```py
mask = 0b0000000100000011
invmask = (~mask & (1 << 16) - 1)

curr = 0
for i in range(16):
        print "{0:016b}".format(curr)
        curr = ((curr | invmask) + 1) & mask
```

It gives:

```py
0000000000000000
0000000000000001
0000000000000010
0000000000000011
0000000100000000
0000000100000001
0000000100000010
0000000100000011
0000000000000000
0000000000000001
0000000000000010
0000000000000011
0000000100000000
0000000100000001
0000000100000010
0000000100000011
```

Thank you for this very interesting question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this indeed works, but I am looking for an algorithm more efficient than this. In particular by avoiding any shifts.

Comment: OK, in this case you can simply pre-calculate `2^n` target values, put them in an array, and index this array by the value in the `0`..`2^n` range.

Comment: Again this works, but it requires 2^n memory, which might me too much and does not scale well for larger types (32- or 64-bit variables). Using a few extra variables is an option, but not 2^n.

Comment: I am afraid you have to choose. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff

Comment: No, I know it's possible, I just cannot recall how.